# Configuring SSH for each user under a given Host

Tags: ssh, authentication

Say I have multiple service users on a server (`example.com`).

- For `foo@example.com` I use SSH with a publickey
- For `bar@example.com` I use SSH with a password

I access both users regularly from my local machine.

Is there a way to configure the `~/.ssh/config` file so that it correctly detects the preferred authentication type based on the user?

In other words, is there a way to configure things *per-user* for a given host?

I'm imagining something like:

```
Host example.com
    User foo
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_for_foo
    User bar
        PreferredAuthentications password
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criteria other than host would use the [Match keyword](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#Match):

```
Match host example.com user foo
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_for_foo
Match host example.com user bar
        PreferredAuthentications password
```

The default order for `PreferredAuthentications` already tries publickey before password. If you want to use key files with the user names always, not just foo@example.com, you can simplify to:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_for_%r
```

---

P.S. [`password` is not the same ssh auth method as `keyboard-interactive`](https://superuser.com/questions/894608/ssh-o-preferredauthentications-whats-the-difference-between-password-and-k). The former is definitely a password, the latter allows sshd to ask for other inputs like a 2FA code.